# Golang segmentation violation with inheritance

Tags: go

Can someone help me understand why this happens like this? I would assume that the inheritance of a function would still work with a nil object.  I'd ideally like to have child get use of the same bar function as a pointer if possible.

```
import "fmt"

type foo struct{}

func (this *foo) bar() string {

    if this == nil {
        return "I'm nil"
    }
    return "I'm NOT nil"

}

type child struct {
    foo // inheret

}

func main() {
    var obj *foo
    fmt.Println(obj.bar()) // this works

    var childObj *child
    fmt.Println(childObj.bar()) // this seg faults
}
```

Here's a [link](https://go.dev/play/p/TdIP1Jh5GfF) to the playground as well.

Comment: Please take the Tour of GO for the absolute language fundamentals. There is no inheritance in Go and it is impossible to model inherttance with embedding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Go it's important to note that embedding `!=` inheritance. And to understand the difference between the two if you want to use embedding to replace inheritance.

You can find some information about the difference between the two in [Effective Go](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#embedding).

But, in my own words, this is what is happening in your example:

Writing `childObj.bar()` is equivalent to writing `childObj.foo.bar()` (accessing the `foo` field of `childObj` and then invoking its method `bar()`). Because `childObj` is `nil`, trying to dereference it to access the field `foo` will be a nil pointer error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're correct I think I'm confusing embedding with inheritance. I've learned to get this to behave how I wanted I can create my child struct with a pointer to foo

type child struct {
 *foo // inheret
}